# Is there a remote API Authentication wrapper library for Philips Hue (in JavaScript/Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, philips-hue

I'd like to control a light-bulb from outside my home network (ideally from an AWS Lambda function).

I understand that doing this is possible, as per [this page](https://developers.meethue.com/documentation/remote-hue-api) (authentication required).

I have defined my app and I have my app's ID, ClientID, ClientSecret and callback URL.

However, the authentication process (OAuth2) is quite complex, although [documented here](https://developers.meethue.com/documentation/remote-api-authentication) (again, you need to be authenticated to access this page).

Is there a library that handles the process for me? Ideally an NPM module ... I found a number of Philips Hue related projects (huejay, js-hue, ...) but none deals with the authentication part for external applications.

PS: I've also posted [this message](https://developers.meethue.com/content/npm-library-make-authentication-process-remote-api-easier) to the Meethue forum, but hope I might get a response here quicker.

PPS: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900657/how-to-connect-backend-service-with-philips-hue-bridge-remotely) is now outdated, I think as there is an official Remote API.

Comment: Aside: cross-posting between fora on the web tends to be discouraged, at least at the same time, since it has the capacity to create duplicate/wasted effort. Would you supply the URL of the duplicate copy, so that in the future, people can click from here to there as well, in case that thread has answers that this one does not have? Please also post the URL of this thread over there.

Comment: @halfer thanks for editing my question! :-) I've added a link to the meethue.com forum question and will do the same over there. Let's hope someone has an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is now built into the latest versions of node-hue-api (which is in npm registry) and provides documentation on setting up the Remote connection using the library: https://github.com/peter-murray/node-hue-api/blob/master/docs/remoteSetup.md

Comment: Peter Murray thanks for the link; I will check it out shortly and then mark your answer as accepted.